# No Resolution to Pygame Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am using anaconda [python 2.7] on ubuntu machine [15.04].

I need opencv, pygame, python 2.7 for my code to run.

I get the error on running my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep_q_network.py", line 8, in <module>
    import wrapped_flappy_bird as game
  File "game/wrapped_flappy_bird.py", line 19, in <module>
    IMAGES, SOUNDS, HITMASKS = flappy_bird_utils.load()
  File "game/flappy_bird_utils.py", line 21, in load
    pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/0.png').convert_alpha(),
pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file
```

Hours spent on this making the fix. TRied SO solutions. PLease help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error: `File is not a Windows BMP file`. The image you're trying to load seems to be a .png: `assets/sprites/0.png`. To fix, save the image as a .bmp. Your pygame is missing support for other formats. [Documentation quote](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html):

> The image module is a required dependency of Pygame, but it only
>   optionally supports any extended file formats. By default it can only
>   load uncompressed BMP images. When built with full image support, the
>   pygame.image.load() function can support the following formats.

To fix it, you need to install python imaging libraries.

Comment: yes, I get that. BUt it should work. I don't want to do conversion for each of my images. That will be ugly I think. Some solution must be there ??? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but installing pil didn't help. I am getting the same error. I tried a different code also, the same error again. :(((((((